# opening worddoc2007 inside webbrowser/c#.net

Tags: c#, browser

I need to open word document inside the webbrowser.

It works when I open word2003, but not word2007. I got some links saying ActiveXwebbrowser will solve this problem. I tried that also but its opening as a new windows explorer not inside the ActiveXwebbrowser.

I am working on a windows application using c#.net.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
openFileDialog.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    object null_obj_str = "";
    string FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
    object loc = FileName;
    System.Object null_obj = 0;
    axWebBrowser1.Navigate2(ref loc, ref null_obj, ref null_obj, ref null_obj_str, ref null_obj_str);
    //axWebBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(FileName));
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work in 2007, do you get an error message?

Comment: no error message.simply not opening inside the browser control .instead opening in a new explorer window. the problem occurs only when i open 2007 worddocument.

Answer (score 0):

> You may want to display or to embed a Microsoft Office document
>   directly on a Microsoft Visual C# form. Microsoft Visual C# 2005 and
>   Microsoft Visual C# .NET do not provide an OLE control that allows you
>   to embed an Office document on a form. If you want to embed an
>   existing document and open it as an in-place ActiveX document object
>   in a Visual C# form, a potential solution for you is to use the
>   Microsoft WebBrowser control.

**Reference:** http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662